# .htaccess RewriteCond not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am copying this code into my .htaccess file but it seems to not be redirecting the IP to the site

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX # I have the IP correct
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] # I have the domain name correct

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

or maybe cause I have a shared hosting ?

Comment: and what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `HTTP_HOST` you should be using `REMOTR_ADDR` for your (client) IP address:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect a particular IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =xx.yy.zz.mm
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

**Make sure you place this rule in `DocumentRoot` of `xx.yy.zz.mm`.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still not working whenever I write my ip address on the address bar it directs me to another page you can see yourself http://160.153.53.99/

Comment: Oh you're accessing the website using this address? Then it will be this condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =160.153.53.99`

Comment: @user3135757 it looks like you are on a shared hosting plattform. i.e. you have to define your virtualhost for your domain. it's not possible to make this with a .htaccess file what you are trying (access your domain by ip) because the webserver serves the default website and not yours.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller I guess that's the case that is why I mentioned it in my question, I'll contact the host provider about that, Thanks all